# Scriptable Amazon S3 windows client?

Tags: windows, amazon-s3

Quick question, simple console client for Amazon S3 at Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer, check out [**s3.exe**](http://s3.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Cloudberry have written Powershell cmdlets that will probably do what you're looking for:

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/default.aspx?page=amazon-s3-powershell

Comment: still haven't managed to get around powershell's syntax/core concept.. :(

Comment: I can relate to that, but it really is time well spent learning Powershell.  I would suggest searching for the Powershell Week webcasts on the Microsoft script centre.  Watch all 5 and you will be surprised how quickly your learning will accelerate after that.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t say what you’re using it for, but one possibility is that you want to automate a process like a software build or a backup.

If you don’t mind a little programming (and only a little, really), try [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/), which is a Python module. We use it in a build script on Windows and it’s very easy. You can do something like this:

```
# Example: Upload an .exe file and make it world readable.
from boto.s3 import Connection
conn = Connection(YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID, YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('some-bucket')
key = bucket.new_key('the_file.exe')
key.set_contents_from_filename('local_path_to_the_file.exe')
key.set_acl('public-read')
```

You can also generate those nifty auto-expiring URLs—something we use for paid downloads:

```
# Example: Get a URL for a file on S3. Make the URL expire after 1 day.
from boto.s3 import Connection
conn = Connection(YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID, YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('some-bucket')
key = bucket.get_key('path/to/your/file')
url = key.generate_url(expires_in=86400)
# Note: 86400 is the number of seconds in 1 day
```

Python has an interactive command-line so it’s easy to experiment with it, too.

Answer (score 0):

I use a java based tool called Jsh3ll. (works in Windows obviously)

https://jsh3ll.dev.java.net/

The main feature that I needed was the ability to use a "commandfile". I.e. I use scripts to generate a text file with all the files I need to upload and then I can run one command to process the whole file. When I did the research 18 months ago or so, this was the only tool that had this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [minio client](http://minio.io/#mc) aka "mc". mc provides minimal tools to work with Amazon S3 compatible cloud storage and filesystems.

mc implements the following commands:

```
  ls        List files and folders.
  mb        Make a bucket or folder.
  cat       Display contents of a file.
  pipe      Write contents of stdin to one or more targets. When no target is specified, it writes to stdout.
  share     Generate URL for sharing.
  cp        Copy one or more objects to a target.
  mirror    Mirror folders recursively from a single source to many destinations.
  diff      Compute differences between two folders.
  rm        Remove file or bucket [WARNING: Use with care].
  access    Manage bucket access permissions.
  session   Manage saved sessions of cp and mirror operations.
  config    Manage configuration file.
  update    Check for a new software update.
  version   Print version.

mc <command> --help will provide example for working on individual commands.
```

PS: I contribute to this project, your feedback & contribution will be helpful to us.